# App deployment with fabric and Git

Tags: git, ssh, fabric

Hello I create a git repository.
After I followed the guide of generation for SSH key, my `git add` and `git commit` are working well.

Against by the following *fabric* script

```
run("git clone git@github.com:myusername/projet.git %s" % repertoire)
```

That gives:

```
returns the error:   
Cloning into /repertoire....

[@ip_server] out: Permission denied (publickey)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the environment variable `HOME` isn't set (or incorrect) within the fabric session.

Make sure of its value, and if you do have your keys stored in `$HOME/.ssh`.

Comment: @MangaDaoud yes, but is HOME defined when from within the python fabric script?

Comment: in the root directory of my Django project

Comment: when i using a local deployement to my application , script work well. But when i want to deploy another serveur the run(git clone ....) return errors

Comment: ouhh it is ok. I'm adding option -b master